# Difficulty to create depth cloud from iphone 11 pro depth map in python

Tags: python, iphone, depth

I am trying to understand how to get the point cloud from the depth map obtained from iphone 11 pro (python). I tried to get the intrinsic matrix using an online exif tool.

```
Intrinsic_Matrix = [[3131.580078125, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3131.580078125, 0.0], [1505.6236572265625, 2004.1282958984375, 1]]
```

I currently have a grayscale image varying between 1-255 representing the depth. I would like to get the depth coordinates (in meters).

Sorry, I only have some basic knowledge in this topic, any help would be appreciated.
Below is the code I tried but failed.

```
img_depth = cv2.imread('Images/image_depth11.jpg')
h, w ,c = img_rgb.shape
new_img = img_depth[:, :, 0]    # single channel
hd, wd = new_img.shape
#imC = cv2.applyColorMap(img_depth, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

# intrinsic matrix iphone 11 Pro

Matrix = [[3131.580078125, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 3131.580078125, 0.0], [1505.6236572265625, 2004.1282958984375, 1]]

focalX = float(wd) * (Matrix[0][0] / wd)
focalY = float(hd) * (Matrix[1][1] / hd)
principalPointX = float(wd) * (Matrix[2][0] / wd)
principalPointY = float(hd) * (Matrix[2][1] / hd)
 distance ( z direction) = 1/Z  ( ie , 1/255 ??)
```

thanks
Nit

Answer (score 1):

For absolute distance, you need to use a TrueDepth camera.

*The TrueDepth camera produces disparity maps by default so that the resulting depth data is similar to that produced by a dual-camera device. However, unlike a dual-camera device, the TrueDepth camera can directly measure depth (in meters) with `AVDepthData.Accuracy.absolute` accuracy. To capture depth instead of disparity, set the activeDepthDataFormat of the capture device before starting your capture session:*

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth

for further details on obtaining (x,y, depth or distance in meters from iPhone lens plane) values for a given pixel (x,y)